# How to make images in a website editable by one user

Tags: javascript, html

i have made a gallery website for my friend now my friend needs to edit the images his own without needing help of me. how to  create a web

Comment: You need an Admin Panel for the website. So basically what you need is to have ability for your friend(admin) to upload remove the images by themselves without your(developer) need.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.